# LocalDateTimeType in FilterDef translates to bigint instead of timestamp

Tags: hibernate

On my entity class I have the following filter definitions:

```
@FilterDefs({
    @FilterDef(name="courseStartsBetween", parameters = {
        @ParamDef(name="startDateTime", type="LocalDateTime"),
        @ParamDef(name="endDateTime", type="LocalDateTime")
    })
})
@Filters({
    @Filter(name="courseStartsBetween", condition="scope_id NOT IN (select scope_id FROM course_time_slot WHERE course_time_slot.end_date_time < :startDateTime OR course_time_slot.start_date_time > :endDateTime)")
})
```

Based on the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic), `LocalDateTime` is a valid BasicTypeRegistry key for Java 8's `LocalDateTime` objects, and the type is mapped just fine. When I now enable the filter as follows:

```
requestContainer.entityManager().unwrap(Session.class)
        .enableFilter("courseStartsBetween")
        .setParameter("startDateTime", septemberFirst.atStartOfDay())
        .setParameter("endDateTime", septemberFirst.plus(1, ChronoUnit.YEARS).atStartOfDay());
```

The query fragment get's properly embedded in the query (show-sql enabled), but then the query fails with:

```
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > bigint
    Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
        Position: 4114
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jar:9.4.1209]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2023) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jar:9.4.1209]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jar:9.4.1209]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jar:9.4.1209]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:166) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jar:9.4.1209]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jar:9.4.1209]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
... 55 common frames omitted
```

This is unexpected as my fields map to the `timestamp` type (which it also should according to the above referenced documentation). How should I map a `LocalDateTime` type in a `FilterDef`?